# Jquery ignorando casas a direita

Tags: javascript, jquery

Montei a função abaixo, para validação de valores em dois campos, um automático (vem do banco) e outro digitado pelo usuário. O que ocorre é que, aparentemente, ele ignora as casas a direita do valor. Por exemplo:

```
function calc_dif() {
  if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
       qtde = null; //ZERA AS DUAS VARIAVEIS PARA NÃO PEGAR LIXO DA MEMORIA
       qtde_trans = null; //ZERA AS DUAS VARIAVEIS PARA NÃO PEGAR LIXO DA MEMORIA

       var qtde_trans = $(this).val(); //VALOR DIGITADO
       var qtde = $(this).closest('tr').find('[name="qtde[]"]'); //campo ao lado
       alert(qtde_trans);
       alert(qtde.val());
       if (qtde.val() < qtde_trans) {
          alert("Não pode transferir mais que o disponível!");
          $(this).val(null);
          $(this).focus();
          qtde = null;
          qtde_trans = null;
       }
  }
}
```

Na função acima, o campo `qtde_trans` recebe o valor 50. O campo `qtde` exibe 2000. Nos alerts os valores são exatamente esses. Mas de alguma forma ele entra no if, como se o `qtde` fosse menor. Agora, se eu digito 20, ele aceita. Mas se digitar 21 ele exibe o erro. Tentei limpar variáveis, como está acima ainda, testei outros métodos para comparar, mas não surtiu efeito. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Experimentou converter pra Number ambos? Number($(this).val()) ? Ah, e também, se certificou que não existe mais de um campo com nome qtde[]?

Comment: Obrigado, acabei de colocar o Number nos dois, deu certo. Só tem um campo com o nome qtde. Pode postar como resposta :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode converter para Number ambos os valores:

```
var qtde_trans = Number($(this).val()); //VALOR DIGITADO
var qtde = Number($(this).closest('tr').find('[name="qtde[]"]').val());
```

E então fazer sua condicional:

```
if (qtde < qtde_trans) { ... }
```

Isso vai garantir que seus valores sejam testados como números. (=

Answer (score 4):

Ele não ignora casas. A menos que haja mais código que você queira nos mostrar*, eu acredito que a comparação é feita entre textos, não números.

Quando você compara textos, a comparação é pela ordem alfabética. E em ordem alfabética 2000 é menor (vem antes) do que 500.

Sugestão: garanta o tipo numérico das variáveis através das funções [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) se for trabalhar apenas com inteiros, e [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) caso contrário.

i.e.:

```
var valorNumerico = parseInt(foo.val()); // trabalhe agora com o valor numerico.
```

* existem plugins para jQuery que fazem com que o valor de inputs de texto específicos possam já ser obtidos como valores numéricos através do método `val`.